# Magento - list categories, subcategories, and images in phtml file

Tags: image, list, magento, url, categories

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu located in header of each of my Magento pages. I want to list all of the categories, the subcategories, and the associated images with each. From scraping and combining code from the Internet, I've come up with a solution that almost works, only the URLs for the subcategories are returning as undefined, and I don't know why. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load(2) -> getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',', $cats);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load($catId);
        $categories[$category -> getName()] = array('name' => $category -> getName(), 'url' => $category -> getUrl(), 'img' => $category -> getImageUrl(), 'subcategories' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> getCategories($catId));
    }
    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
        <li><?php echo $data['name']; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
            </a>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ($data['subcategories'] as $subcategory) {
                    echo "<a href='" . $subcategory -> getUrl() . "'><li>" . $subcategory -> getName() . "</li></a>";
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512171/magento-displaying-all-categories-but-cannot-get-associating-images/14513074#14513074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 'subcategories' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> getCategories($catId)
```

to

```
  'subcategories' => $category->getChildrenCategories()
```

See [How To Get Sub Categories in Magento ?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926121/how-to-get-sub-categories-in-magento)